# prevent optimization from discarding metadata

Tags: clang, llvm

I add some metadata to the IR file in an EP_EarlyAsPossible pass. However, I find that some of the metadata is discarded. I guess it is due to optimization. Anyway to stop discarding metadata?

Comment: You don't need to guess, you can [find out using `opt -p`.](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html)

Comment: During compilation, I print out all metadata I added. After compilation, I searched inside ll file and find some of them is discarded.

Comment: What you have now is "one or more of 200-odd things is removing some unspecified metadata from unspecified instructions under unspecified conditions" which is really too broad for this site. You can narrow it down a great deal using `opt -p`.